# Print related object of related object python

Tags: python, django

I am creating a guide app where each guide is made of 3 classes as bellow.

How do I for example print subtask 3 of step 2 in guide 1

This is what I can do in the shell so far.

```
class Guide(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, default=1)
    guide_category = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    guide_title = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    guide_how = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    guide_why = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    guide_logo = models.FileField()
    is_complete = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.guide_title + ' - ' + self.guide_category + ' - ' + self.guide_how + ' - ' + self.guide_why


class Step(models.Model):
    guide = models.ForeignKey(Guide, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    step_title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    is_complete = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.step_title


class Subtask(models.Model):
    step = models.ForeignKey(Step, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    subtask_title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    subtask_description = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    subtask_image = models.FileField()
    is_complete = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.subtask_title
```

This is what I can do in the shell so far.

```
from appname.models import Guide, Step, Subtask
guide1 = Guide(pk=1)
guide2 = Guide(pk=2)
>>> Guide.objects.all()
[<Guide: Test1 - CR - how1 - why2>, <Guide: test2 - VR - how2 - why2>]
>>> Step.objects.all()
[<Step: 1>, <Step: 2>, <Step: 1>, <Step: 2>]
>>> Subtask.objects.all()
[<Subtask: 1.1.1>, <Subtask: 1.1.2>, <Subtask: 1.2.1>, <Subtask: 1.2.2>, <Subtask: 2.1.1>]
```

Thanks! :)

Comment: guide = Guide.objects.get(1);step = guide.step_set.filter(id=2); print(step.subtask_set.filter(id=3))

Comment: Thank you! But I get a type error when I do:

    >>> guide = Guide.objects.get(pk=1)
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 122, in manager_method
        return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
      File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 387, in get
        self.model._meta.object_name
    DoesNotExist: Guide matching query does not exist.

Comment: because Guide with id == 1 does not exists

Answer (score 0):

If you have `guide1`, then,

```
subtasks = Subtask.objects.filter(step__guide=guide1)
```

`subtasks` would be a queryset of `Subtask` objects related to `guide1`.
You could then get the subtask with any additional conditions.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Subtask(models.Model):
    step = models.ForeignKey(Step, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    subtask_title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    subtask_description = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    subtask_image = models.FileField()
    is_complete = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return ' '.join([self.subtask_title, '.'.join([str(self.step.guide.id), str(self.step.id), str(self.id)])])
```

and test it:

```
Subtask.objects.all()
```

Comment: Thanks again! :D 
I still haven't figured it out but I did the .join change your showed me and got this when typing Subtask.objects.all()

   ' taskoftheday/models.py", line 35, in __str__
        return ' '.join([self.subtask_title, '.'.join([self.step.guide.id, self.step.id, self.id])])
    TypeError: sequence item 0: expected string, int found  '

Comment: answer updated ;) for TypeError: sequence item 0: expected string, int found '

Answer (score 0):

> How do I for example print subtask 3 of step 2 in guide 1

There is a fundamental issue here, because you don't have anywhere in your models where you define the order of tasks for a specific step. So there is no "third task", there is just the "task #3" which may belong to any of the steps.

So, you need to first, enhance your tasks model so that there is an order, so it is easy to print the order in which tasks need to be completed.

Here is a simplified model set that implements this:

```
class Step(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
   guide = models.ForeignKey('Guide', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

   class Meta:
      order_with_respect_to = 'guide'

class Task(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
   step = models.ForeignKey('Step', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

   class Meta:
      order_with_respect_to = 'step'

class Guide(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

You can use it like this:

```
g = Guide.objects.create('Guide 1')
step = Step.objects.create('Step 1')
task = Task.objects.create('Task 1')
last_task = Task.objects.create('Last Task')
task3 = Task.objects.create('Third Task')
task2 = Task.objects.create('Second Task')

# Add them first
step.task_set.add(task)
step.task_set.add(last_task)
step.task_set.add(task3)
step.task_set.add(task2)

# Get the default ordering, which is by primary key:

step.get_task_order()

# Arrange the tasks in the right order by the primary key:

step.set_task_order([task1.pk, task2.pk, task3.pk, last_task.pk])

# Finally, add it to the guide
g.step_set.add(step)
g.save()
```

Now, when you retrieve the tasks, they will be in the right order. Now you can do this, which is "get the third task, in the second step, of the first guide":

```
Guide.objects.get(pk=1).get_step_order()[1].get_task_order()[2]
```

The documentation goes into some more details about [`order_with_respect_to`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/options/#order-with-respect-to).